# Can't put animate() in script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an javascript script, but i can't put animate() in this.

```
<script language="javascript">

    function appear(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("about");
        .animate({elem.setAttribute("style","z-index: 9999;")},800);
     };

    </script>
```

How i do this?

Comment: You should probably start here though -> http://learn.jquery.com/

Comment: `$('#about').animate({'z-index':9999},800);`

Answer (score 3):

`.animate()` is a method, not a stand-alone function.  That means you can't call it by itself; you can only call it by operating on a jQuery object.  So, `.animate(...);` doesn't work, but `$(....).animate(...);` can work. For example,

```
<script language="javascript">

function appear(){
    $('#about').animate({zIndex: 9999},800);
};

</script>
```

**Edited** to fix the `elem....` notation.

**Additional explanation**

Functions work like this:

```
function foo(bar) {
    return bar + 1;
}
foo(1); // returns 2
```

That is, they are called out of context, by themselves.

Classes work like this (in JavaScript):

```
function MyObject() { }
MyObject.prototype.foo = function(bar) {
    return bar + 1;
};
x = new MyObject();
x.foo(1); // returns 2
```

Comment: Oh, thank for the response, but it doesn't work :(
I have called the jquery in my page, before the </body> closed.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Doesn't work how? What error do you get? By the way: animating the `z-index` change is probably not going to do what you think, unless you are writing a game or something.

Comment: I understand what you say, the effect i expect doesn't work. I tried to this with pure CSS but the effect doesn't work too.

Comment: Well, since we don't know what effect you are going for, it's hard to say.  Do you just want to fade it in? If so, just do `$('#about').fadeIn(800);`.